# How to access services outside an Azure VM?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-enterprise, azure

We have a federated base deployment of ArcGIS Enterprise on an Azure Machine.

My question is to know/find out how to access the services published on portal outside of that Azure Machine?

As of now accessing services outside the server machines(Azure) triggers an error, which is expected.

[image]

I believe its an certificate issue, and if that's the case. Will creating a Domain Certificate resolve this issue? As per my understanding the Domain Certificate would only allow services within a specific domain network and the azure machine has nothing to do with the domain neatwork I guess as its connected via Azure VPN.

Comment: It should be no different than standard ArcGIS server access i.e., what is the name of the Azure instance? In AWS it is something like https://randomname-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/arcgis/rest/services... Just because it's on Azure doesn't make a difference it's still all the same operations and virtual folders in the URL, what is different is the beginning as you see in the AWS URL. For certs - ArcGIS Server has a self-signed certificate, but did you install a certificate on all the web adaptors? I wouldn't focus on certs though until you have a functioning URL.